# Working with multiple dataset in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

In my SSRS report, I have three different datasets bringing data from different data sources.  Unfortunately, I cannot combine them into one.

What I am trying to accomplish:
I need a report that has three tables (for each data source) in one page and only displaying information for a specific Account.

[image: My dataset table structure:]

How I want to see the results:

[image]

I am able to Group each table by Account Number and then add page break to display in separate page.  However, I cannot figure out how to display all three table data in one page.

Also, I need to make sure the report is still exportable to Excel with all the data. I am not sure if subreport will allow me to export to Excel without any issues

Answer (score 0):

If you create one tablix on your report with dataset 1 you can insert sub reports into it for dataset 2 and dataset 3. See this question for details on that [Nested Sub-Report in Tablix SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24744728/nested-sub-report-in-tablix-ssrs). This will allow all of the data to display in one table. To have one page per account you need to set the page break on the account grouping for the main tablix. See the image below.

Usually I try not do this as it is much harder to manage and maintain the report with all of the different pieces. Combining the data sets into one is really your best option.
[image]

Comment: The problem is I only have Two parameters (startdate and enddate)  for the table.  How would I be able to link both reports to a specific Account Number and only display that specific data?

Comment: Following the instructions, my two reports are showing within one of the rows of my main tables.  Also, the sub-report is not repeating every page.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You would have to modify the other 2 datasets to accept the account number as a parameter. This way when they are called for each iteration of the group in the main dataset it is account specific.