# How can I pass and process an array of varchars as parameters to/within a SQL Server stored procedure parameter?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, parameter-passing, dml

I use an existing stored procedure that declares these parameters:

```
@Unit varchar(4000),
@BegDate datetime,
@EndDate datetime,
@SortBy varchar(20)
```

The challenge I now face is coming up with a derivation of that stored procedure which takes any number of @Unit parameters, from 1..N

How can I do that? Is it a matter of changing the @Unit parameter to @Unit varchar(max), assigning delimited values to the parameter, and then parsing the delimited-value from within the stored procedure?

IOW, do I need to do something like this in the stored proc:

```
@Unit varchar(max),
@BegDate datetime,
@EndDate datetime,
@SortBy varchar(20)
```

...this in the C# code:

```
string unit = unit1 +',' + unit2 +',' + unit3 // and on for however many units are being added
. . .
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unit", unit);
```

...and then, back in the stored proc, parse the comma-delimited values into a string array and have it query the table like so (pseudo-dml):

```
string[] unitArray = @Unit.Split(',');
. . .
SELECT BLA, BLEE, BLOO FROM F_BUELLER WHERE Unit in unitArray[0], unitArray[1], unitArray[2], // and on for however many units are being queried for
```

...or what/how?

NOTE: If this were a "normal" project (non-SSRS, that is), I would simply use the original stored proc, calling it multiple times, and amalgamating the returned data, grouped by Unit. I don't know if that's possible or how to do it from SSRS, in an rdl/xml file, though...

### UPDATE

What really needs to happen here is that there be a page break after each unique "Unit", the reason being that the report is exported to Excel, and the requester wants each Unit on its own separate sheet.

So basically I need to call the same stored procedure N times, plopping the results each time on its own "page."

So the tip [here](http://forums.devshed.com/ms-sql-development-95/using-multiple-stored-procedures-report-sql-server-reporting-services-280259.html) seems to be good ("you can create multiple datasets in Reporting Services and then use them in different elements in the report. Just add a  from the Dataset: dropdown on the data tab")

The crux of the biscuit is, though: how can I provide 1, and only 1, dataset for each Unit? There is no way to know in advance how many units/sheets are going be generated/needed; there could be a couple, there could be a couple dozen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I've done this is by passing in a delimited string as a report parameter.

Build a dataset in the report which shreds the delimited string into rows using XML casting. Assuming that the @Unit parameter is comma-delimited when there is more than 1 value, the dataset query would look something like this:

```
DECLARE @UnitXml XML = CAST('<unit>' + REPLACE(@Unit,',','</unit><unit>') + '</unit>' AS XML)

SELECT unit.x.value('.','VARCHAR(200)') AS [unit]
FROM @UnitXml.nodes('/unit') AS unit(x)
```

Then make a tablix that has a row for each item in the dataset.

Put a subreport in the row group of the tablix. In your case, the subreport would point to a report part showing all the info for one Unit, and passing the unit number from the dataset to your stored procedure.

The stored procedure would run once for each Unit. I realize this is neither elegant nor efficient but this is SSRS.

Comment: I am a bit confused by this because (a) someone downvoted it (I upvoted it to get it back to 0); I don't know if the downvote was valid or not - if so, what's wrong with this approach? (b) I'm only an occasional dabbler (on an as-needed basis) in SSRS, so would need more specifics to make heads or tails of this answer - at this point, it seems almost like "voodoo programming" to me.

Comment: This post explains adding subreports: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24744728/nested-sub-report-in-tablix-ssrs

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of SQL Server Table Type Parameter.

Create a Type first in SQL Server

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TVP_Units] 
AS TABLE(
 [Units] VARCHAR(1000)
)
GO
```

Make Your Stored procedure accept a variable of that type instead of a Varchar(1000) @Units variable.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE MyProc 
  @TVP_Units [dbo].[TVP_Units] READONLY
, @BegDate datetime
, @EndDate datetime
, @SortBy varchar(20)
....... rest of the code
```

I am not an expect in C# but your C# code would look something like ....

```
using (con)
{                

 //Create a DataTable ....

    DataTable _dt = new DataTable("Units");
    _dt.Columns.Add("Unit", typeof(string));
    _dt.Rows.Add("Unit 1");
    _dt.Rows.Add("Unit 2");
    _dt.Rows.Add("Unit 3");

    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.MyProc", con);
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlParameter tvpParam = sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TVP_Units", _dt); 
    //tells ado.net it is a TVP
    tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured; 

    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BegDate", YourC#Param);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", YourC#Param);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SortBy", YourC#Param);
    con.Open();
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

Comment: I wish it was C#, which I am comfortable with (also not really an expert), but I need to do this in SSRS / the rdl file.

Comment: 99% sure SSRS won't accept a user-defined table-valued type parameter. At least I couldn't ever get it to work.